# Unable to search the word if there are special characters in it using match-sorter library javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, match

I have the following array of objects.

I want to search the word `Powai` (case insensitive). But when I search the word I am not getting the results with the word `(Powai)` with parenthesis. I have attached the code below the JSON. Please help.

I am using https://github.com/kentcdodds/match-sorter this library along with the `<Autocomplete />` component of Material-UI react to filter the results based on the input query.

```
[
{
      "id": 31,
      "name": "Powai",
    },
  {
      "id": 3474,
      "name": "Powai Chowk Mulund",
   },
  {
      "id": 3475,
      "name": "Powai Vihar Complex",
    },
  {
      "id": 2428,
      "name": "Forest Club Powai",
    },
  {
      "id": 2635,
      "name": "Hiranandani Powai Bus Station",
    },
  {
      "id": 3561,
      "name": "Ramda Hotel (Powai)",
    },
  {
      "id": 2244,
      "name": "Crisil House (Powai)",
    },
  {
     "id": 2662,
      "name": "I.R.B.Complex(Powai)",
    },
  {
      "id": 2890,
      "name": "Kingston Sez (Powai)",
  },
  {
      "id": 3972,
      "name": "Tatapower Centre (Powai)",
 },
  {
      "id": 2362,
      "name": "Dr.Ambedkar Udyan (Powai)",
  },
  {
      "id": 2389,
      "name": "E.S.I.S.Local Office Powai",
 },
]
```

- `match-sorter` version:  `^4.1.0`
- `node` version: `12.14.0`
- `npm` (or `yarn`) version: `6.14.4`

Relevant code or config

```js
matchSorter(options, inputValue, {
    keys: ["name"],
    threshold: rankings.WORD_STARTS_WITH,
    keepDiacritics: true,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by changing the `threshold` value to `threshold: rankings.CONTAINS`.

That solved my problem.